# Read MVC model in AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I send a request to get the GeneralDictViewmodel object and its dictionaries but it gets only itself, not its dictionaries in the AJAX response. How can I solve this?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: getAllGeneralDictUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data, status, resObject) {
            alert("success..." + data); 

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });


    public JsonResult GetAllGeneralDict()
    { 
            GeneralDictServiceClient generalDictSvc = new GeneralDictServiceClient();
            GeneralDictViewModel generalDictRes = new GeneralDictViewModel();
            generalDictRes.ShipTypes = generalDictSvc.GetGeneralDict("SHIP_TYPE").ToDictionary(x => x.KEY_ITEM, x => x.VALUE_ITEM);
            generalDictRes.BodyMaterials = generalDictSvc.GetGeneralDict("BODY_MATERIAL").ToDictionary(x => x.KEY_ITEM, x => x.VALUE_ITEM);
            generalDictRes.Designations = generalDictSvc.GetGeneralDict("DESIGNATION").ToDictionary(x => x.KEY_ITEM, x => x.VALUE_ITEM);
             return Json(generalDictRes);
    }
```

Comment: Seems there is a problem in your URL. Use url: getAllGeneralDict instead of  url: getAllGeneralDictUrl,

Comment: but it send request to action . I could debug it

Comment: when I send return(new String("something" )) it work but not work with model . Is is possible to have problem with model's property which are Dictionary ?

Comment: Typo issue no ? `getAllGeneralDictUrl`,No action method of that name no ?

Comment: I declared in script ->  var getAllGeneralDictUrl = '@Url.Action("GetAllGeneralDict", "GeneralDict")';

Comment: as I said it find action but response is not correct form. cant get Shiptypes dictionary .it said it is undefined

Comment: How are you trying to access the related dictionaries in the `success` function? How do you know that they are undefined?

Comment: I just try to get length

Comment: or i try to get object in console. it is undefined written

Comment: Can you show the code in which you are trying to get the length or print in the console in which you are getting undefined?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should should "GET" in your ajax call if you are fetching data.

```
try {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'template/GetAllGeneralDict',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data, status, resObject) {
            alert("success..." + data);

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    window.location.href = SiteRootPath + "default.aspx";
    $('#loading').hide();
}
```

Second : You should write  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet with the JSON data in your return function on Controller

```
public JsonResult GetAllGeneralDict()
        {
            var abcObj = new Animal() { Id = 1, Name = "ZTom" };

            return Json(abcObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```